# How can I have two or more registrations edit pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a settings tab which links to the user to `edit_user_registrations_path` corresponding to the devise/registrations/edit.html.erb page.

I created another page under devise/registrations called edit_account.html.erb and I'd like this to allow the user to edit additional settings like Twitter and any other social networks that allow it.

I keep getting a routing error. This is the route I tried using with no luck:

```
devise_scope :user do get "/edit/edit_account" => "devise/registrations#edit_account" end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the error and your rake routes...

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it in my routes file is like this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  put "edit/edit_account", :to => "devise/registrations#edit_account",
                           :as => "edit_account"
end
```

and then like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => edit_account_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks TMP, now I just need to sort out this line -- as it's throwing up a undefined method model_name error::   <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

Comment: Any luck? Basically, the form_for in the secondary edit page is causing an error. What should I change that too to work with the new route?

Comment: Oh sorry, you'd want to change the URL to whatever your new one is called